# Split UITableview horizontally in IOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a SQLite project in IOS for Ipad. the database contains one table with a lot of products. what I want to do is separate this products into categories. so that i can make a separate tableview for each category. So my question is, can I use one table view with different sections, but put this sections side by side horizontally? The application only work on landscape mode. I hope the question is clearly enough. Thank's.

[image]

Comment: do you want the two sides to scroll independently or together?

Comment: there are more than two,the idea is to put every table or section inside a scrollview perhaps?

Comment: This discussion may help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636848/horizontal-movement-of-a-uitableview?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a UICollection view (iOS6+ only, but there is an open source back-port [here](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView)), or you can roll your own using scroll views.

The collection view scrolls horizontally, and has a number of items matching the sections in your catalogue.

Each cell of the collection view contains a header and a table view, holding the detail from the appropriate section.

Use child view controllers to keep your code clean - the view for each cell should be managed by its own view controller, which doesn't need to know it is in a collection view cell.

Comment: Yes I know that way, but i need o put a table for every category, there are more than 2.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you perhaps draw a simple diagram and add it to your question?